What's the right statistical test in python
I have two datasets, one has predicted values (with confidence levels) and the other has actual values (as well as some unknowns)
What I am trying to do is determine what confidence level we need so we are happy to use the predicted value in place of the unknowns.
I'm not sure what the best test to use here
Ideally I was going to do it through python, but happy to do whatever is best!
Thanks,
N
